# Problemas de propagacion de un input personalizando en react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, input, react-select

Estoy personalizando los componentes de react-select, en el componente del MenuList agrego un input

```
            <Select
                isClearable
                options={data}
                getOptionLabel={({ name }) => name}
                getOptionValue={({ id }) => id.toString()}
                components={{
                    MenuList: CustomMenuList,
                }}
            />


const CustomMenuList = (props: MenuListProps<IF_DataProps>) => {
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

    const handleInputChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        // e.preventDefault();
        // e.stopPropagation();
        setInputValue(e.target.value);
    };

    
    return (
        <components.MenuList {...props}>
            <input
                value={inputValue}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
                onMouseDown={handleInputMouseDown}
                onClick={handleInputClick}
                className="border"
            />
            {props.children}
        </components.MenuList>
    );
};
```

El problema resulta que al momento de hacer click para ingresar valor este se cierra automaticamente el menu, intente prevenir la propagacion pero no funciona

```
   const handleInputMouseDown = (e: MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        // e.preventDefault();
    };

    const handleInputKeyDown = (e: KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        // if (e.key === "Backspace") {
        // }
    };

    const handleInputClick = (event) => {
        // event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    };
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me pueden apoyar para poder llegar a la solución, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: seguramente en ```<components.MenuList {...props}>``` hay un metodo que está causando que se cierre el menú, puedes intentar convirtiendo el return en un Fragmento y poner el menú como hermano del input, no el input como "children" del menú